# rails rufus scheduler does not run in daemon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm currently loading my rails app as a daemon with 'rails s -d'

I'm trying to schedule the following task

```
scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.new

scheduler.every '1h' do
      begin    
        puts "Actioning scheduler"  
        system("source ~/.bashrc")
        system("bundle exec rspec")

      rescue Exception => e    
        puts e 
      end
 end
```

Nothing seems to happen when i run the rails server as a daemon, but if i start it up normally there is no problem.

Using rails 4.0, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: even i am facing the same problem? Any solutions for this ?